# Using separate controllers and routes in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am looking for subjective advice (and I know this might get closed), but I want to be able to separate routes and controllers in a node.js project so I have some questions:

- Is it useless to try and is the node.js philosophy to have fewer/larger JS files?
- I want to be able to require("routing") and have it wire up all my routes to the required module for my controllers. I can do this easily if I just put everything in `index.js` but that seems odd. I am already doing `app.get("/" controllers.index);` style separation, but I am getting hung up on building a module that just includes all JS files in another module. Am I missing something?
- Or maybe there is a completely different node.js style to do this, and I am trying to map my ASP.NET MVC knowledge too deeply?

Comment: Try a lightweight express-flatiron MVC https://github.com/pksunkara/bullet/tree/master/example/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to get it all into one file, you might try something like this, which requires every file in `./routes/` and calls the function exported to each with `app` as the parameter:

```
// routing.js

var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(app) {
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/routes/').forEach(function(name) {
    var route = require('./routes/' + name);
    route(app);
  });
}

// routes/index.js

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/something', function(req, res) { ... });
  app.get('/something/else', function(req, res) { ... });
}

// routes/pages.js

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/pages/first', function(req, res) { ... });
  app.get('/pages/second', function(req, res) { ... });
}

// server.js

var app = express.createServer();
require('./routing')(app); // require the function from routing.js and pass in app
```

There are also some interesting examples in Express' `example` directory on GitHub, such as [an MVC-based one](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc) which implements RESTful routes much like Rails would.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to do some RESTish API server,
give it a try: https://github.com/kilianc/node-apiserver
also examples: https://github.com/kilianc/node-apiserver/blob/master/examples